# vaadin 23 how do i get my grid to autoupdate every few minutes?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin23

I'm new to vaadin and currently I'm doing this project at work and have to make a grid autoupdate from the database, can anyone help me?

I've looked around for documentation and tried using TimeTask but it did not work.

Comment: What did not work? Please show some code. Basically you have to enable serverpush and then updated the data provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Push in your application in order to send asynchronous updates to the client. Here, asynchronous means something that doesn't happen because the browser sends a request to the server, so for example something that is executed with a timer.

In Vaadin 23, enabling Push is done by adding the `@Push` annotation on a class that `implements AppShellConfigurator`, typically the `Application` class. Updates from a background thread need to use the `ui.access()` method to avoid conflicts in the session. There are configuration options for using Push that you can find from the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/server-push